# Disambiguate the diamondproblem in c++ to access the top level member

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, multiple-inheritance

First I would like to acknowledge that there are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064880/diamond-problem) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264304/diamond-problem) [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383840/how-does-the-compiler-internally-solve-the-diamond-problem-in-c) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704332/c-resolving-the-diamond-problem) [titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561729/can-the-diamond-problem-be-really-solved) and subject matter. I'm fairly certain mine is unique from them.

Given the code

```
struct Top {
    int get() {
        return 0;
    }
};

struct Mid1 : Top {
    int get() {
        return 1;
    }
};

struct Mid2 : Top {
    int get() {
        return 2;
    }
};

struct Bottom : Mid1, Mid2 {

};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    Bottom b;
    std::cout << b.Mid1::get();
    std::cout << b.Mid2::get()
    std::cout << b.Top::get();
}
```

I get an error on the line trying to access `Top::get()` with the error (using gcc mingw-w64)

```
 error: 'Top' is an ambiguous base of 'Bottom'
 std::cout << b.Top::get();
```

I get an error. How would one signal to the compiler to call `Top::get`on a specific inheritance path in this case?

Comment: Which `Top` should `b.Top::get();` use?

Comment: Use virtual inheritance for `top`

Comment: It's unusual to see a diamond problem that doesn't feature the keyword `virtual`

Comment: while using virtual is probably better code, using the virtual keyword does not solve this problem

Comment: @NathanOliver The one the user specifies. basically I'm asking how to specify

Comment: Where did you insert `virtual`?

Comment: As I understand the problem, `Top::get()` can only be called on an object of class `Bottom` because `Bottom` is ultimately derived from `Top`. The problem is, how is it derived? There are two paths leading from the parent class to the grandchild, and no way to decide which path to take. And I don't know of a way to tell the compiler to take either one .

Comment: @Eugene right before "`int`" in `Top`, `Mid1`, and `Mid2`

Comment: That's a virtual function, not virtual inheritance.

Comment: @Eugene I think I'm somewhat lacking in my knowledge of subtle differences between the two. I'll have to do my research. If the difference between the two allows an answer feel free to post

Comment: @TimRandall "*I don't know of a way to tell the compiler to take either [path]*" - see my answer

Comment: Seen it, up-voted it, appreciated it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bottom` is a [derived class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class) that is not using [virtual inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance), so it has 2 distinct instances of `Top` - one inherited from `Mid1`, and another from `Mid2`.  As such, you must explicitly tell the compiler which instance of `Top` you want to call `get()` from, eg:

```
std::cout << b.Mid1::get(); // OK
std::cout << b.Mid2::get(); // OK
std::cout << b.Top::get(); // ERROR!
std::cout << b.Mid1::Top::get(); // ERROR!
std::cout << b.Mid2::Top::get(); // ERROR!
std::cout << static_cast<Mid1&>(b).Top::get(); // OK
std::cout << static_cast<Mid2&>(b).Top::get(); // OK
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/CldyUc)

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for in an answer. A bit ugly, but I wouldn't really expect much else.

Answer (score 0):

Is your intention to have 2 copies of `Top` inside `Bottom`? If it is, then use the answer from Remy Lebeau. But if you instead want to have a single copy of `Top` inside `Bottom`, then use virtual inheritance:

```
struct Mid1 : virtual Top {...}
struct Mid2 : virtual Top {...}
```

In this case, your original code

```
std::cout << b.Top::get();
```

will compile.